# Regex to unsplit one-liner string that is split into multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

- Let's say I have the following string:

```
str = '''I love to eat apple and 
bananas but at the same time, I do
not like to eat oranges 
and I am not a fan of vegetables.

I also like to eat biscuits.
I also like to eat crackers.

Meanwhile, oddly enough, I have never liked
ice creams or chocolates because I
am never a sweet-toothed.'''
```

- Hence, how do I combine the multiline strings into a single line? i.e. so I would end up with the following:

```
new_str = '''I love to eat apple and bananas but at the same time, I do not like to eat oranges  and I am not a fan of vegetables.

I also like to eat biscuits.
I also like to eat crackers.

Meanwhile, oddly enough, I have never liked ice creams or chocolates because I am never a sweet-toothed.'''
```

[EDIT!]
To be clearer, I am considering cases where a one-liner text is being split into multiple lines. Hence,

1. I want the regex to check whether the next line belongs to the previous line (i.e. maybe by checking whether the first letter in the next line is a small letter)
2. In cases like this where you have,

```
str = '''I also like to eat biscuits.
I also like to eat crackers.'''
```

I do not want these two sentences to be merged as they each belong to two different sentences as in I do not want this,

```
new_str = "I also like to eat biscuits. I also like to eat crackers."
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `re`! Use the `sub` module like this:

```
import re                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                     
s1 = """I love to eat apple and                                                                                      
bananas but at the same time, I do                                                                                   
not like to eat oranges                                                                                              
and I am not a fan of vegetables.                                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
I also like to eat biscuits.                                                                                         
                                                                                                                     
Meanwhile, oddly enough, I have never liked                                                                          
ice creams or chocolates because I                                                                                   
am never a sweet-toothed.                                                                                            
"""                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
new_s1 = re.sub("\n(?!\n)", " ", s1)                                                                                       
                                                                                                                     
print(new_s1)
```

Comment: Hi @JustLearning, perhaps my question is not that clear. What I am considering are cases when you have a single line of string being split into multiple lines. I want my regex to check whether the next line is a line that belongs to the previous line (i.e. maybe by checking whether first letter in the next line is small letter) and merge them until it encounters a punctuation.

Comment: Hence, your regex is not really helping in this case. Please refer to my edited post. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple `str.split` might be enough:

```py
text = '''\
I love to eat apple and
bananas but at the same time, I do
not like to eat oranges
and I am not a fan of vegetables.

I also like to eat biscuits.

Meanwhile, oddly enough, I have never liked
ice creams or chocolates because I
am never a sweet-toothed.'''

for group in text.split('\n\n'):
    print(group.replace('\n', ' '))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
I love to eat apple and bananas but at the same time, I do not like to eat oranges and I am not a fan of vegetables.

I also like to eat biscuits.

Meanwhile, oddly enough, I have never liked ice creams or chocolates because I am never a sweet-toothed.
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely, perhaps my question is not that clear. What I am considering are cases when you have a single line of string being split into multiple lines. I want my regex to check whether the next line is a line that belongs to the previous line and merge them until it encounters a punctuation.

Comment: Hence, your code is not really helping in this case. Please refer to my edited post. I hope you can help me, thanks so much.